# База консолидатор

Tags: java, postgresql

Добрый день. У меня есть задача по реализации реляционной базы - консолидатора на базе Postgres. Т.е. есть автономные удаленные базы Postgres с одинаковыми схемами и необходимо создать единую базу где будут консолидироваться данные со всех удаленных баз. Подскажите есть ли какие-то решения в этом направлении, куда можно покопать. В ручную реализовывать не очень хочеться)) Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Может ли подойти мультимастер репликация?
[одна из статей](https://habrahabr.ru/post/327674/)

Если это не подходит, может по расписанию через [rest интерфейс постгреса](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API) получать новые данные со всех БД. В промежуточном приложении проводить консолидацию данных и записывать в общую БД. Но в данном случае придется дополнять схему консолидированной базы информацией какой ноде соответствует запись и идентификаторы записей в ноде.